Proof of a mathematical step involving trigonometric functions
On a scientific paper I found a strange step, from this ($\theta$ and $\phi$ are time-dependent; $\gamma$, $g$, and $l$ are constants):
$$
\ddot{\theta} - \ddot{\phi} - \ddot{\theta} \, \cos(\phi) + \dot{\theta}^2 \, \sin\left( \phi \right) + \frac{g}{l} \, \sin\left( \theta - \phi - \gamma \right) = 0
$$
to this:
$$
\ddot{\theta} - \ddot{\phi} + \dot{\theta}^2 \, \sin\left( \phi \right) - \frac{g}{l} \, \cos(\theta - \gamma) \, \sin(\phi)= 0
$$
Could you tell me how to get the last result please?


I guess it used $\sin(\theta-\gamma-\phi)=\sin(\theta-\gamma)\cos(\phi)-\cos(\theta-\gamma)\sin(\phi) $

@Morten Mathematica told me that the right and the left parts of the equation you wrote are different (see the edit please)...could you write the proof please?

@Morten that doesn't account for the change. My guess is there is some information missing here. What happened to the $\ddot{\theta}\cos(\phi)$ term?

@FedericaGuidotti You know that $\sin(x-y)=\sin(x)cos(y)-cos(x)sin(y)$ and then let $x=\theta-\gamma$ and $y=\phi$.

@ChrisLewis Right, it requires $g\sin(\theta-\gamma)=\theta l$.

@ Federica Guidotti: Please give a screen shot or paper reference so that angles can be properly identified,  in what appears to me as a non-linear pendulum problem.

@Morten Did you mean $g\sin(\theta-\gamma)=\ddot\theta l$?

Thank you @Morten your suggestion solved my problem, the missing information was the relationship $\ddot{\theta} - \frac{g}{l} \sin(\theta - \gamma) = 0$.

This looks like a physics reasoning but it starts as @morten correctly said, using the fundamental trigonometric identity he mentioned, and then you can proceed using a physics pendulum/oscillation relation which seems to be prerequisite knowledge in the document you read.
The steps are as follows:
$$\ddot{\theta} - \ddot{\phi} - \ddot{\theta} \, \cos(\phi) + \dot{\theta}^2 \, \sin\left( \phi \right) + \frac{g}{l} \, \sin\left( \theta - \phi - \gamma \right) = 0$$
can be rewritten as
$$\ddot{\theta} - \ddot{\phi} - \ddot{\theta} \, \cos(\phi) + \dot{\theta}^2 \, \sin\left( \phi \right) + \frac{g}{l} \, \left[ \sin\left( \theta - \gamma \right)\cos\left(  \phi \right) - \cos\left( \theta - \gamma \right)\sin\left(  \phi \right)\right]= 0$$
that is,
$$\ddot{\theta} - \ddot{\phi} - \ddot{\theta} \, \cos(\phi) + \dot{\theta}^2 \, \sin\left( \phi \right) + \frac{g}{l} \,  \sin\left( \theta - \gamma \right)\cos\left(  \phi \right) - \frac{g}{l} \, \cos\left( \theta - \gamma \right)\sin\left(  \phi \right)= 0$$
you then group the $\cos\left(\phi \right)$ factors as follows:
$$\ddot{\theta}  - \ddot{\phi} + \, \cos(\phi) \left[  \frac{g}{l} \,  \sin\left( \theta - \gamma \right) - \ddot{\theta}\right] + \dot{\theta}^2 \, \sin\left( \phi \right) - \frac{g}{l} \, \cos\left( \theta - \gamma \right)\sin\left(  \phi \right)= 0$$
Now comes the physics. The variable here is $\theta$ and therefore, using the familar equation from the pendulum (or pendulum-like), the quantity
$$\left[  \frac{g}{l} \,  \sin\left( \theta - \gamma \right) - \ddot{\theta}\right]$$
is actually equal to zero. Rigorously speaking we should know what initial conditions are stated in the document you quote, and I am guessing it related to the $\gamma$ constant. That factor then disappears from the equation and you are left with
$$\ddot{\theta} - \ddot{\phi} + \dot{\theta}^2 \, \sin\left( \phi \right) - \frac{g}{l} \, \cos(\theta - \gamma) \, \sin(\phi)= 0$$
